# malloc assigns same adresses to different arrays

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm trying to initialize some arrays as follows:

```
unsigned int t(sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ);
m_data = (double*) malloc(t*sizeof(double));
m_func = (double*) malloc(t*sizeof(double));
m_tmp = (double*) malloc(t*sizeof(double));
```

However, what happens is that at some point, when checking the adresses of the array elements, they coincide, so the elements are the same( I get the first half of the first array before the second overlaps).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `t` have a value of zero?

Comment: What is `(sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ)` ? A product of three large numbers ?

Comment: Why is the `t` thing written as if this was C++? You meant `const size_t t = ...`, not a constructor call.

Comment: Copy/paste the actual C code.

Comment: t is a large number, iniitialized as a product of unsigned ints. And I use the code in a c++ program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides your obvious syntax error (for C), you have two major problems in your code

1. your size calculation may overflow, that is why you always should use `size_t` as type for "sizes", not only for your result `t`, but also for the other variables `sizeX`
2. you are casting the return of `malloc`. In C, this can mean that you are quieting the compiler for its error message that he doesn't know `malloc`. If so you forgot to include the correct header file. (The error you encounter then would be that your addresses from `malloc` are first converted to `int` and then back to pointer type. On 64 bit platform this looses information.)

Comment: Actually, I am coding in C++. Changing unsigned int to size_t is what made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't know what your `t(...)` does, but when `t` is a number, the result is exactly what you'd expect, three different memory block's addresses:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int t = 2*3*4;
    double *m_data = malloc(t*sizeof(double));
    double *m_func = malloc(t*sizeof(double));
    double *m_tmp  = malloc(t*sizeof(double));

    printf("array1 pointer: %p\n"
           "array2 pointer: %p\n"
           "array3 pointer: %p\n", m_data, m_func, m_tmp);

    free(m_data);
    free(m_func);
    free(m_tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
array1 pointer: 0x7ff528c038c0
array2 pointer: 0x7ff528c03980
array3 pointer: 0x7ff528c03a40
```